# jq update json from another json

Tags: json, jq

I have a defaults.json and a current.json.

defaults.json gets copied to current.json, and current.json is used as the main configuration file.

defaults would looke something like this:

```
{
      "AttributeName":"setting1"
      "Value": [
        {
          "ValueName": "Disabled",
          "ValueDisplayName": "Disabled"
        },
        {
          "ValueName": "Enabled",
          "ValueDisplayName": "Enabled"
        }
      ],
      "DefaultValue": "Enabled"
    }
```

and current.json would look like this:

```
 {
      "AttributeName":"setting1"
      "Value": [
        {
          "ValueName": "Disabled",
          "ValueDisplayName": "Disabled"
        },
        {
          "ValueName": "Enabled",
          "ValueDisplayName": "Enabled"
        }
      ],
      "DefaultValue": "Enabled",
      "CurrentValue": "Enabled"
    }
```

Now when I add a new "setting2" (which has the same keys, but values can be different) to defaults.json, I would like to update current.json with that setting, without overwriting the "currentvalue" field. How can I do this using jq?

I tried things like `jq -rs 'add' defaults.json current.json` but this just prints current.json.

I've tried looking at some of the other questions regarding jq, but they all cater to a very specific situation, uncomparable to mine.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is very unclear, e.g. what does `add a new "setting2"` mean? Which updated values in default.json should be propagated to current.json? It almost seems you need both the original "default.json" and the changed "default.json"?

Comment: It means that I would like to add the object setting1, but with name setting2, and with some different values. See it as a settings menu where a new setting is added. I then want to add the new setting to current.json while preserving the "current value" fields. I have to do it this way because of the way software updates are set up on my platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following jq program first finds the "new" paths in default.json by subtracting the paths in current.json from the paths in default.json, and then updates the "current" JSON by adding all the "new" paths and their associated values:

```
jq --argfile default default.json '
 . as $current
 | ([$default|paths] - [$current|paths]) as $new
 | reduce $new[] as $p ($current; 
     setpath($p; $default|getpath($p)))
' current.json
```

#### Caveat

As of this writing, the --argfile option is officially "deprecated", so you might like to use one of the many other ways to pass in the contents of default.json.

Comment: What if an object is removed though?